# Read Timer Trigger Schedule from Configuration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a function app DLL project and I want to be able to change the schedule of a timer trigger with configuration but the schedule is passed as an attribute parameter. Meaning, that I can only pass in compile time values rather than dynamically.

Is there a way to read it from app settings or elsewhere so I don't have to make a code change whenever I want to update a schedule?

Here's an example of what I presently have with the attribute parameter

```
[Function("MyTimeTriggeredFunction")]
public static async void Run([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("Doing some timely work ...");
    // and other stuff .....
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Define your trigger as `[TimerTrigger("%myschedule%")]` and then add an application setting `myschedule` with appropriate value (e.g. `*/15 * * * * *`).

See [Binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-expressions).

Comment: Perfect! That answered my question. I've yet to see that in the azure documentation. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is no longer applicable to isolated process hosting model, may not even work. See similar issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/255). You might be able to provide it through env variables.